# What is the value of __cplusplus for C++17?

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

We are trying to test some code under C++17 and its [change to `std::uncaught_exception`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27741423/608639). I can't seem to get GCC to provide the value of `__cplusplus`:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/g++ -std=c++17 -dM -E - </dev/null | grep __cplusplus
cc1: warning: command line option '-std=c++1z' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
$
```

And:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/g++ --version
g++-mp-6 (MacPorts gcc6 6.1.0_0) 6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

What is the value of `__cplusplus` when using C++17?

Comment: Add the switch `-xc++` (it still ptobably won't be correct though)

Comment: I believe that the most recent standards drafts still have the old C++14 value, so there isn't an official one yet.

Comment: If all you want is to test whether `std::uncaught_exceptions` is available, you should use the [feature testing macro](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations#recs.cpp17) `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions`.

Comment: Thanks Galik. GCC should be invoking cc1plus rather than cc1... Now open on the GCC bug tracker: [Issue 71930: g++ invokes the wrong preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71930).

Comment: Thanks cpplearner. I'm guessing (and its only a guess) some compilers won't use `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions`. Microsoft's VC++ and SunCC come to mind. I've found `__cplusplus` is a better test because it paints with a broad brush. I can then one-off the compilers that do their own thing, which is usually VC++.

Comment: There is no C++17 yet.

Comment: Thanks Nicol. We are trying to get ahead of the upcoming changes for C++17. Especially the ones that have the propensity to cause trouble for us.

Comment: If everything gets wrapped up in the Toronto meeting, then perhaps it will be 201707.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

#### tl;dr: For C++17,  `__cplusplus` is `201703L`.

> What is the value of `__cplusplus` when using C++17?

According to the draft standard [N4594](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) *§16.8/p1 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
> `__cplusplus` The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value
> **201402L** when compiling a C++ translation unit.<sup>156</sup>
>
> <sub>156) It is intended that future versions of this standard will
> replace the value of this macro with a greater value. Non-conforming
> compilers should use a value with at most five decimal digits.</sub>

However the same value is appointed for the C++14 standard. Apparently it seems so, that there's no official/standard `__cplusplus` value set yet for the C++17 standard.

In GCC versions 6.1 and 7.0 the value is changed to **201500**

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434f55846912a5ff)

In Clang version 3.8 and 3.9 the value is unchanged **201406**.

Consequently, you'll have to wait a little bit for the standard value to come out.

### --- Update ---

According to the C++ standard *§19.8/p1 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> <sub>1</sub> The following macro names shall be defined by the
> implementation:
>
> `__cplusplus` The integer literal **201703L**.

Thus, the value of `__cplusplus` when using C++17 shall be **201703L**.

Comment: Ah, I missed your update... I see `g++ -x c++ -std=c++14 -dM -E - </dev/null` returns `#define __cplusplus 201402L` for GCC 7.3.

Comment: I take it `__cplusplus` doesn't return the same value for Visual Studio 2017 when setting the language option specifically to c++17? I get `199711` returned when using the macro.

Comment: Hm, okay, that's actually an open bug right now... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/120156/-cplusplus-macro-still-defined-as-pre-c11-value.html

Answer (score 18):

I would try:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201402L
  // C++14 code here
  ...
#endif
```

In other words, testing for greater than C++14 should work as compilers add more features. As someone mentioned above, GCC uses `201500L`. It looks like clang uses `201406L` (four months after C++14 I guess).

Using the above snippet should be cross-platform and will work even when C++17 comes out with real value for `__cplusplus`.  For more details about evolving features try the [feature test macros](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations).

Comment: Personally, I think SD-6 should include __cpp_1998 __cpp_2011 macros that give you the exact month and year.

Comment: What is more correct? to say `#if __cplusplus >= 201703L` or `#if __cplusplus > 201402L`?

Comment: @alfC `#if __cplusplus > 201402L` would be true on c++1z, 17, currently 2a... and so on, but not c++14 or before that. In other words, this can be useful when using any old compiler before March 2017, given that you are using a ready-to-use feature of the c++17 that the old compiler already provides. When using recent compilers, I would prefer `>= 201703L` more.

Comment: The 201500L was used in a pre-c++17 version. So it would not clash with c++14 and was not a complete C++17 compiler either... (for example the `[[fallback]]` attributes would not work right even though it was semi-recognized.)

Answer (score 16):

Normally you should use `__cplusplus` define to detect c++17, but by default microsoft compiler does not define that macro properly, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/ - you need to either modify project settings to include `/Zc:__cplusplus` switch, or you could use syntax like this:

```
#if ((defined(_MSVC_LANG) && _MSVC_LANG >= 201703L) || __cplusplus >= 201703L)
     //C++17 specific stuff here
#endif
```

Answer (score 7):

I realize you asked this question citing the Gnu C++ compiler as the one you're using, but you may want to have some awareness of what happens on the Visual C++ compiler, and strictly speaking, your question didn't ask about a specific compiler.

Currently, as of the date of this posting, the VC++ 2017 compiler sets `__cplusplus` to `199711L` rather than what you might expect if you set the compiler to use c++17.

To get it to report correctly, you have to also set `/Zc:__cplusplus`.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2017 )

As to why?  Well... in their words:

> We tried updating the macro by default and discovered that a lot of
>   code doesn’t compile correctly when we change the value of
>   __cplusplus.

(source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know why `__cplusplus` doesn't show up as a regular macro, but I'm guessing it's so you can't redefine it.  This is how I determine the its value.

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then compilation shows the value.

```
$ g++-6 test.cpp && ./a.out
201402
$ g++-6 -std=c++17 test.cpp && ./a.out
201500
```

I would check whether it's `>= 201500` as opposed to checking for any specific value.

Answer (score 3):

A modern compile time check that you can put in any file that needs it:

```
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L, "This file expects a C++17 compatible compiler.");
```