# How do I check for C++20 support? What is the value of __cplusplus for C++20?

Tags: c++, macros, c++20

Related to questions [How do I check for C++11 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support) and [What is the value of __cplusplus for C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456127/what-is-the-value-of-cplusplus-for-c17)

How can I inquire whether the compiler can handle / is set up to use C++20? I know that it is, in principle, possible to inquire the C++ version by:

```
#if __cplusplus > ???
  // C++20 code here
#endif
```

What should `???` be for C++20?

Comment: Test for greater than 2017 does not work?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Of course! Why didn't I think of that? Whatever the value for C++20 will be will be larger than the one for 17.

Comment: In most cases, prefer to test the [*features*](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined) you require, rather than the language version.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's too early for that.

Until the standard replaces it, use:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201703L
  // C++20 code
#endif
```

since the predefined macro of C++20 is going to be larger than the one of C++17.

As @SombreroChicken's answer mentions, [[cpp.predefined] (1.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.1) specifies (emphasis mine):

> `__cplusplus`
>
> The integer literal `201703L`. [Note: It is *intended* that future versions of this International Standard will **replace** the value
>   of this macro with a **greater** value.]

---

The macros used, as of Nov 2018, are:

- GCC 9.0.0: `201709L` for C++2a. [<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rdX2omv9a1BIkgjc)
- Clang 8.0.0: `201707L`.     [<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9nVpP2XigfBCo0pK)
- VC++ 15.9.3: `201704L` (as @Acorn's answer mentions).

---

PS: If you are interested in specific features, then [[cpp.predefined] (1.8)](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.8) defines corresponding macros, which you could use. Notice though, that they might change in the future.

Comment: gcc 8.2 uses `201709` for `c++2a` and clang 7.0 uses `201707`

Comment: Same for GCC 9 and Clang 8 @bolov, updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: It is not nice to copy other answers after you already have the accepted and top-voted answer :-)

Comment: Yes I agree @Acorn. However, notice how some people are improving their answers in parallel. I see that our answers have a lot in common, just like yours with Sombrero Chicken. If you think, I should modify my answer to improve the gain the future user will have from reading this, then let me know. In any case, if you think yours should be accepted instead, then no problem, your answer is very good :)  Also let's clean these up later, for the sake of the future user please.

Answer (score 55):

The value for C++20 is `202002L`, as you can see at [[cpp.predefined]p1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.1):

> `_­_­cplusplus`
>
> The integer literal `202002L`. [ *Note*: It is intended that future versions of this International Standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value. — *end note* ]

Therefore, for compilers that already implement the new standard, you can check by:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 202002L
    // C++20 (and later) code
#endif
```

This is the compiler support so far:

- **Clang** >= 10
- **GCC** >= 11
- **MSVC** >= 19.29 (requires [`/Zc:__cplusplus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus))
- **ICX** >= 2021
- **ICC**: No (version >= 2021 defines `202000L`; notice the `0`)

Comment: Surely you want `>=` for the 202002 test?  Hopefully C++23 will not break *most* C++20 features…

Comment: > 201703L will not be sufficient. GCC 8 for instance uses 201709 and it's partial C++2a support.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão I'll clarify. Edit: I removed it entirely, it is already 2021...

Comment: @Acorn Thanks! 

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão np!

Comment: It should be noted that for Microsoft C++ compiler testing `__cplusplus` is useless, because you cannot be sure that whoever is using your code is going to set `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler switch or even have it available in their compiler version and without that switch `__cplusplus` will always return the same version (`199711L`). The only way to reliably test on Microsoft C++ compiler is to use `_MSVC_LANG` macro which didn't exist before VS 2015 Update 3 so you also have to test for that compiler version or greater.

Answer (score 7):

There's no known `__cplusplus` version yet because C++20 is still in development. There are only drafts for C++20.

The [latest draft N4788](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4788.pdf) still contains:

> `__cplusplus`
>
> The integer literal `201703L`. [Note: It is intended that future versions of this International Standard will replace the value
> of this macro with a greater value. —end note]

As for checking it, I would use @gsamaras answer.

Comment: @gsamaras just because you asked nicely